# Select calling element in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a quick way in javascript to select the element that called the function on an event such as onmouseover or onclick or do i have to use standard document selection in the method to select the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/this_Operator)

```
element.onclick = function () {
    // this == element
    // e.g. this.className = 'Highlighted';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check out `this`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right then you should be able to use the "this" keyword.